# Parent/child checkboxes with label

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'd like to have parent/checkboxes with this behavior :

1. A click on the parent select/unselect all children
2. Parent is checked if one or more child is selected
3. Parent is unchecked if no child is selected

That code works:

```
<ul class="list-group" id="mydiv">
   <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="parent1" id="parent1" value=""> <label for "parent1">Parent 1</label>
      <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="child11" value=""> Child 11</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="child12" value=""> Child 12</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="child13" value=""> Child 31</li>
      </ul>
   </li>

   <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="parent2" value=""> Parent 2
      <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="child21" value=""> Child 21</li>
         <li class="list-group-item"><input type="checkbox" name="child22" value=""> Child 22</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   $(this).next().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',this.checked);
   $(this).parents('ul').prev('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',function(){
      return $(this).next().find(':checked').length;
   });
});
```

My concern is that as soon as I set a < label > tag, it doesn't work anymore. I can't figure out why.

Here is Pen : https://codepen.io/Jibeji/pen/povYKXo

Comment: If parent gets checked when one of it's children is checked (BTW parent/child relationships doesn't really exist between void elements like `<input>`) that might be too confusing to the user. Say a child is checked then the parent is checked as well...that means that a parent can incur 3 states yet have only 2 indications: **1. parent unchecked:** all children are unchecked, **2. parent checked:** All children are checked, **3. parent checked:** ***some children are checked?***

Comment: I understand your point but that is the behavior I need.

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself. This is more elegant and supports labels:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil('li').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',this.checked);
   $(this).closest('ul').siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked',function(){
      return $(this).nextUntil('li').find(':checked').length;
   });
});
```

Original Pen edited.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work anymore because `$(this).next()` no longer refers to the next input since there are labels there. It seems you want `.next().next()`. You might want a different way to select the `ul` though because you can see how easily this setup can break.

Comment: Thanks for the info tenor528. Do you have any recommandation for a more robust script ? These checkboxes are dynamically generated, the number can change, here is why I was looking for a generic solution